# Make hover work or capture mouse enter events on the scrollbar of an iframe?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, hover, scrollbar

When I try to use hover or mouse enter events on a div box that contains an iframe with scrollbars I find the following issues in IE9-:

1. When I approach mouse to the box and hit the extern "border" of the scrollbar, "mouse enter" event fires.
2. If I keep going into the scrollbar, "mouse leave" event fires as if the scrollbar was not part of the box.
3. If I leave the scrollbar and go into the box "mouse enter" event fires again.

How can I make the scrollbar of the iframe work as the rest of the box?
In Firefox it works well.

The HTML

```
<div class="hover_point">
    <iframe height="250" width="250" src="www.20minutos.es"/>       
</div>
```

The CSS

```
<style>
    .hover_point{width: 250px; height:250px}
</style>
```

The JS

```
$(".hover_point").hover(function () {
    alert("hover");             
},
function () {
    alert("no hover")
});
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kFUYp/

Comment: Quick tip: if you're debugging, **particularly with mouse events**, don't use `alert()`, use `console.log("hover")` and the messages will be logged to the dev tools' console.

Comment: The first thing I would try is declaring a position on both the div and the iframe, then giving the div a higher z-index than the iframe.

Comment: Thanks Robbie, you are completely right. mgrahamjo, that was also my first idea, didn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems z-index issue please follow below rule to fix z-index issue.

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 3000">
 <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1000;">
    <a href="#">Page</a>
    ...
</div>
</div>
```